# Retrieving response from network and print with Python

Tags: python, tornado

I have a problem.
I've written this part of code in Python (Tornado web server):

```
if command == 'RESTARTNWK':
        op_group = "A3"
        op_code = "E0"
        netid = hextransform(int(nid), 16)
        packet_meta = "*%s;%s;%s;#"
        pkt_len = hextransform(0, 2)

        packet = packet_meta % (op_group, op_code, pkt_len)
        packet = packet.upper()

        op_group_hex=0xA3
        op_code_hex=0xE0

        cmdjson = packet2json(op_group_hex,op_code_hex, packet)

    mynet_type="ztc"

    print("\t\t " + packet + "\n")

    #TODO : -write command into db  
    ts = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
    mynet_type ="ztc" 
    self.lock_tables("write", ['confcommands'])
self.db.execute("INSERT INTO confcommands (network_id, ntype, timestamp, command) \
                              VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", nid, mynet_type, ts, cmdjson)
    self.unlock_tables();

    # TODO: - open the /tmp/iztc file in append mode
    cmdfile = open('/tmp/iztc', 'a')
    #       - acquire a lock  "only for the DB case, it's easier"
    #       - write the packet 
    cmdfile.write(netid + "\t"+ mynet_type + "\t"+ ts + "\t"+  cmdjson +"\n");
    #       - release the lock "only for the DB case, it's easier"
    #       - close the file
    cmdfile.close()

    if command == 'RESTARTNWK':
        opcodegroupr = "A4"
        opcoder = "E0"


    #Code for retrieving the MAC address of the node
    como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port,
                        '/', ztc_config, '?netid=', netid,
                        '&opcode_group=', opcodegroupr, 
                        '&opcode=', opcoder, '&start=-5m&end=-1s'])
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)

    ret = {}
    if response.error:
        ret['error'] = 'Error while retrieving unregistered sensors'
    else:
        for line in response.body.split("\n"):
            if line != "": 
                value = int(line.split(" ")[6])

    ret['response'] = value
    self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
    self.finish()
```

In this code I receive the restart network command from the user. After some settings, I write the relative command in a db table named confcommands. The server will read this command and will send to the specified network the restart signal.

After this, if all it's ok, the network resend me the response. I read this response with a http request to my server (como), and wait for the asynchronous response.

Where the response is written by the network, I have to find this in the packet. The value response is the sixth element. Other information of the packet are the opgroup and opcode, the network from which is the response, and other informations.

Then I write the response for the user.

I don't know if this code is right... can work this? The structure seems to me right....

Thank you all for any suggestions!

Comment: You seem to get the value and write it as a response, what exactly is the problem? Is it the RequestHandler finishing before your response is ready? (I'm guessing this by the look of your other related questions)